# how would i generate a random lowercase string the length of the users entered number

Tags: c++

Hello I am attempting to write a function that will generate a random string of lowercase letters. The length of the random string will be the number the user entered. I have this much so far but i believe i am over complicating things

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

char randString(){
int number;

     str::string Str; //str has not been declared error
     for(unsigned int i = 0; i <8; i++){
     Str += randString(); //str was not declared in this scope error
     }
     cout << Str << endl; // str was not declared in this scope error
}


int main() {

    char c;
    int number;

    srand (time(0));

    cout << "Enter a number.\n"
            "That number will generate a random string of lower case letters the length of the number" << endl;

    cin >> number;

    for (int i=0; i < number; i++){
        number = rand() % 26;
        c = 'a' + number;
        cout << randString();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your recursion has no base case

Comment: @self It's not called at all, thank god.

Comment: Why are you using recursion at all? Also `rand()` is garbage and there's a lot of better [random number generators in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: `str::string` -> `std::string`

Comment: Why does `randString` exist if you're not using it?

Comment: @immibis didnt add the randString() to the last cout

Comment: Ask yourself: What is `str`?

Answer (score 0):

You changed the value of the variable `number` inside your for loop, which is also your loop condition variable. This will cause an undefined behavior since the value of `number` will be changed every time the statement `number = rand() % 26;` is executed. However, from what I understood reading your problem statement, I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    char c;
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "Enter a number.\n"
        "That number will generate a random string of lower case letters the length of the number" << endl;
    cin >> number;
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
    {
        c = 'a' + rand()%26;
        cout << c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!